# Error al imprimir variables con javascript en alert();

Tags: javascript, html

Perdonen la pregunta por lo absurda que es, pero ando un poco desgastado en JavaScript jaja
no es un error de javascript, es un error mío xd
lo que quería hacer es introducir datos en un (dos) inputs y que me los imprima en un alert(), pero no imprime las variables, solo cadenas de texto
gracias de antemano

```html
<html>
<head>
<!-----Para usar texto y simbolos----------->
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<!-----------Formulario------------>
<input type="text" placeholder="Escribe tu nombre..." id="nombre">
<input type="text" placeholder="Escribe tu edad" id="edad">
<button onclick="mostrarAlerta()" value="">Mostrar mi información</button>
<!--------Javascript----------->
<script>

/* Creamos la funcion que muestra la alerta */
function mostrarAlerta() {

alert(nombre + " " + "tiene" + " " + edad + "años");

 }
  /* Recogemos el nombre */
var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
/* Recogemos la edad */
var edad = document.getElementById('edad').value;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Básicamente se resuelve recuperando el `value` dentro del contexto de la función quedando así:

```
function mostrarAlerta() {

alert(nombre.value + " " + "tiene" + " " + edad.value + "años");

 }
     /* Recogemos el nombre */
var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre');
/* Recogemos la edad */
var edad = document.getElementById('edad');
```

O bien mueve adentro de la función las 2 variables que obtienen a tus inputs, no tiene caso declararlas por fuera si no las vas a pasar como argumentos al momento de llamar a tu función en tu HTML en el evento `click`

Si no tienes problema en cambiar la estructura propongo que no coloques la lógica de ejecución de la función fuera del HTML invocando al botón en su evento click una vez recuperado por medio de una variable quedando así:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Escribe tu nombre..." id="nombre">
<input type="text" placeholder="Escribe tu edad" id="edad">
<button id="boton" value="">Mostrar mi información</button>
<!--------Javascript----------->
<script>


let nombre = document.getElementById('nombre');
let edad   = document.getElementById('edad');
let boton  = document.getElementById("boton") 


boton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  alert(`Tu ${nombre.value} tienes ${edad.value}`)
})
```

Comment: Si, creo que con el evento click se hace un poco más entendible, y un poco más rápido a la hora de estar escribiendo